# Spring boot security to allow all endpoints except one

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

For a project that has no spring security. All controllers (GET/POST) of the project are not secured and should stay unsecured. But now, I have a new Controller and i want to secure its path (`/private`), sub-pathes and parameters. Only this one path must be secured with Basic Authentication. Why is my code not working?

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/private**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").and().httpBasic();

    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password("{noop}pass")
                .roles("ADMIN");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/private").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/private/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
```

or

```
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/private").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/private/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216357/discussion-on-answer-by-kavithakaran-kanapathippillai-spring-boot-security-to-al).